# What's the strongest refresh method available to ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

I have five layers: polygon, line, and point with a single IRasterLayer file.  I am programmatically setting the ILayer.Visible attribute for the Raster but the layer is not refreshing.  If I zoom in, or zoom out, then it refreshes properly.

I tried these two methods:

```
mapControl.Refresh();
mapControl.Refresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll, null, null);
```

But they didn't refresh my map.  What method is stronger that this for refreshing the entire map?

Comment: Strange, have you tried [mapControl.ActiveView.Refresh()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Refresh_Method/0012000001np000000/)?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall Thanks Kirk, I had forgotten about that one.  If you make an answer I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [mapcontrol.ActiveView.Refresh()](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Refresh_Method/0012000001np000000/) is more reliable.